# InStr always returns 0

Tags: sql

I am using instr to locate the starting position of a substring I am trying to extract and it seems to return 0 no matter what I do. The source string's format can vary slightly, so I'm not sure if I can just use substr to find it. I've tried using both binary and textual comparisons and both return 0. My code looks like this:

```
select instr('_20',name,1) from <table name>
```

Source string looks something like AA-000000-00_20000000_AA.pdf. It returns 0 even when I shorten the string to just '2'.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Looks like it might be the wrong way around, this works for MySQL.
SELECT INSTR("AA-000000-00_20000000_AA","_20") 

https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_instr

Comment: Oracle 12.2.0.1.0

Comment: @JonTout This solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 1st and 2nd parameters are the wrong way round. The function is documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm